Fusion Chart loads 1 in every 5+ page refreshes (Razor pages on .NET)
I've put together a web app using Blazor server in VS, and the issue I face is this chart is only appearing when it wants to when loading the app in Edge. No messages, errors.. nada. Then I noticed if I keep hitting refresh, it appears, even when the page fails to render it, you might see it flicker for a split second then vanish.
It's obviously some loading/timing issue I've checked everything.
Not sure what to try. That's why I am here. I'm expecting to see my lovely report when loading the app in Edge.
[Code Block@code {
    private string? dataSourceJson;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var eventData = await FetchEventDataFromDatabase();
        PrepareChartData(eventData);
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender && dataSourceJson != null)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("renderFusionChart", dataSourceJson);
        }
    }

    private async Task<List<DailyAlarmData>> FetchEventDataFromDatabase()
    {
        return await context.AlarmData
            .Where(a => a.EventTime.HasValue)
            .GroupBy(a => a.EventTime.Value.Date)
            .Select(group => new DailyAlarmData
                {
                    Date = group.Key,
                    Count = group.Count()
                })
            .ToListAsync();
    }

    private void PrepareChartData(List<DailyAlarmData> eventData)
    {
        var chartData = new
        {
            chart = new
            {
                caption = "Daily Event Count",
                subCaption = "For the current month",
                xAxisName = "Day",
                yAxisName = "Number of Events",
                theme = "fusion"
            },
            data = eventData.Select(e => new { label = e.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), value = e.Count }).ToList()
        };

        dataSourceJson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(chartData);
    }

    public class DailyAlarmData
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
}


Thanks for having a stab GL. I'm lost in the woods here and happy to share the responsible razor page:

I'm unsure of what you have tried as you have supplied no code.
but having had a look at their documentation on thier website looks like its written for blazor web assembly opposed to server.
I'd update you code to possibly move the call for it to
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()

OR
[Parameter]
public string JsonData{ get; set; }

protected override void OnParametersSet()

Putting in the call to render the component into either of these
For EG
await _jsruntime.InvokeAsync<String>("FusionCharts.invokeChartFunction",functionName, chartId, args);
      

Then as its blazor server try calling afterwards.
StateHasChanged();

This will tell blazor server to update the UI ... hopefully.
FOR more information on statechanges and rendering check out
ASP.NET Core Razor component rendering Docs
Fusion Charts extended docs:
github has more examples than their website docs
GL.
